# に with action verbs

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に

> 日本**に**留学すれば、日本料理が食べられるようになります。

Why is に used in this particular sentence?

I'd use で because I think する is an action verb, not a state verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This に is a destination marker, the same に as in 日本に行く. You can say 日本**へ**留学すれば, too. It's also possible to say 日本で留学すれば, but we usually prefer に/へ. You can find examples [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%95%99%E5%AD%A6/example/). (So this means that "to study abroad" sometimes does not work as a direct translation of 留学. I think we have to remember this fact.)